# Create UIButtons random position without intersection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, intersection, arc4random

I have 6 uibuttons in an array. And i want to set random positions for them without intersection. I tried a few things and my project works fine. But when i force the app to generate new buttons, it stucks without an error.

```
for (UIButton *button in arr) {

    float widthOffset = self.gameView.frame.size.width-button.frame.size.width;
    float heightOffset = self.gameView.frame.size.height-button.frame.size.height;

    button.frame = CGRectMake(arc4random()%(int)widthOffset, arc4random()%(int)heightOffset, button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height);

    while ([self button:button intersectsButtonInArray:arr]) {
        button.frame = CGRectMake(arc4random()%(int)widthOffset, arc4random()%(int)heightOffset, button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height);
    }
}


-(BOOL)button:(UIButton *)button intersectsButtonInArray:(NSArray *)array {
    for (UIButton *but in array) {
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(button.frame, but.frame) && ![button isEqual:but]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

In my opinion, the problem is in while part. But i can't figure out.

Any advice is appreciated.

Best Regards,
Taha

Comment: does it always get stuck or does it get stuck sometimes only..?

Comment: It always stucks. Sometimes in 3rd refreshing , sometimes in 15th.

Comment: what are the values of `widthOffset` and `heightOffset`...?

Comment: `widthOffset` and `heightOffset` are local variables. I use them to determine the bounds.

Comment: you generate random numbers with them... so it means if offset value is 5 it will generate number only between 0 to 5...

Comment: Yes i know that. I tried to keep buttons in view thats why i use these two variables.

Comment: If your buttons fill or very nearly fill their superview, there a good chance that when you get to the last one, it will take a long time to pick a random position that happens to be available in the view..?

Comment: @GeorgeGreen Thank you! I just set buttons frame (widht and height) more smaller and it works great now.